# How to get the value of a sibling node in XSLT within a for-each loop

Tags: xslt

I am trying to get the value stored in a sibling node in a for-each loop with distinct values of another sibling node:

My XML:

```
<LaunchedMeterClass id="584e348b-2a06-42d0-a858-b8909f579238-St-4M-Template-Standard-cF">
    <property key="ClusterContractUUID" value="c2cebd90-9265-4cea-8018-0aac6efcced2"/>
    <property key="OVClustered" value="true"/>
</LaunchedMeterClass>
<LaunchedMeterClass id="584e348b-2a06-42d0-a858-b8909f579238-St-4M-Template-Standard-cE">
    <property key="ClusterContractUUID" value="c2cebd90-9265-4cea-8018-0aac6efcced2"/>
    <property key="OVClustered" value="true"/>
</LaunchedMeterClass>
<LaunchedMeterClass id="584e348b-2a06-42d0-a858-b8909f579238-St-4M-Template-Standard-cC">
    <property key="ClusterContractUUID" value="d0c9f440-172c-49ad-9b95-cddce23f16fa"/>
    <property key="OVClustered" value="false"/>
</LaunchedMeterClass>
<LaunchedMeterClass id="584e348b-2a06-42d0-a858-b8909f579238-St-4M-Template-Standard-cD">
    <property key="ClusterContractUUID" value="d0c9f440-172c-49ad-9b95-cddce23f16fa"/>
    <property key="OVClustered" value="false"/>
</LaunchedMeterClass>
```

My XSLT (doesn't work):

```
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="//LaunchedMeterClass/property/@key='ClusterContractUUID'">
    <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(descendant::property[@key='ClusterContractUUID']/@value)">
        <contract-type>
            <property>
                <xsl:attribute name="key">ClusterContractUUID</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="value">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </property>
            <property>
                <xsl:attribute name="key">OVClustered</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="value">
                    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[1]/property[@key='OVClustered']/@value"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </property>
        </contract-type>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
    <contract-type>
        <property>
            <xsl:attribute name="key">contractTypeCategory</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="value">service</xsl:attribute>
        </property>
    </contract-type>
</xsl:otherwise>
```

My desired result:

```
<contract-type>
    <property key="ClusterContractUUID" value="c2cebd90-9265-4cea-8018-0aac6efcced2"/>
    <property key="OVClustered" value="true"/>
</contract-type>
<contract-type>
    <property key="ClusterContractUUID" value="d0c9f440-172c-49ad-9b95-cddce23f16fa"/>
    <property key="OVClustered" value="false"/>
</contract-type>
```

I also tried ancestor::, descendant:: and preceding-sibling:: etc. but I always got this error: Required item type of the context item for the following-sibling axis is node(); supplied value has item type xs:anyAtomicType.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`distinct-values` gives you a sequence of strings (or primitive values in general), not a sequence of nodes. Primitive values don't have siblings. You need to use `xsl:for-each-group` if you want to group nodes.

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="LaunchedMeterClass" group-by="property[@key='ClusterContractUUID']/@value">
  <contract-type>...</contract-type>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

I think, to copy the `property` element, you simply want

```
<xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="LaunchedMeterClass" group-by="property[@key='ClusterContractUUID']/@value">
    <contract-type>
        <xsl:copy-of select="property"/>
    </contract-type>
  </xsl:for-each-group>    
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hello Martin,
Thank you for the quick reply! I tried to use the for-each-group but it still doesn't work:

    <xsl:for-each-group select="LaunchedMeterClass" group-by="property[@key='ClusterContractUUID']/@value">
        <contract-type>
            <property>
                <xsl:attribute name="key">ClusterContractUUID</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="value">
                    <xsl:value-of select="./property[@key='ClusterContractUUID']/@value"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </property>
   <other properties...>

Comment: I have edited the sample, if you simply want to copy all `property` elements of the first item in the group then it is as easy as `<xsl:copy-of select="property"/>`. If you want to copy the property elements of all items in the group then you can use `<xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/property"/>`. If you need to transform some child elements use `<xsl:apply-templates select="property"/>` respectively `<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/property"/>` and write a template that transforms the `property` elements as needed.

Comment: Sure. Thank you very much!